# Bad theory import in isabelle

Tags: isabelle

The following gives `bad theory import "Multivariate_Analysis"`

```
imports Multivariate_Analysis
```

Importing `Main` works fine, how do I import modules?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For theory imports, you usually have to specify the full or relative path to the theory file. So for `Multivariate_Analysis`, this is `<path to isabelle distrib>/src/HOL/Multivariate_Analysis/Multivariate_Analysis`. The path may be only omitted if the theory is already part of the session image. So as `Main` is part of the default image `HOL`, you can import it without a path. Opinions diverge whether it is better to import theories from session images with or without paths.

The path may also contain environment variables like `$ISABELLE_HOME` or `$AFP`, which users can set in their local settings file such that the theories work across different installations. For everything from the Isabelle distribution, it is custom to use `~~` for the path of the Isabelle distribution folder.

In summary, your import should read as follows:

```
theory My_Theory
imports "~~/src/HOL/Multivariate_Analysis/Multivariate_Analysis"
begin
```

As `Multivariate_Analysis` is a fairly large module, it might be sensible to change the default session image, though, such that all these theories are not loaded at every start of Isabelle/jEdit afresh. You can do so by specifying `-l HOL-Multivariate_Analysis` at the command line upon invocation or by selecting this session in the theory panel and restarting Isabelle/jEdit.

Update: Since Isabelle2017, it is preferable to import theories from other sessions via session names instead of relative path names. That is, the 
theory `Multivariate_Analysis` would be imported as

```
theory My_Theory
imports "HOL-Multivariate_Analysis.Multivariate_Analysis"
begin
```